# After installing Debian, can't update

Tags: debian, updates, repository

I tried editing the sources.list file to update the repo but it didn't work. Here is my list atm:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 lxde-CD Binary-1 $

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 lxde-CD Binary-1 20$
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch  main contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib
# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
# deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

When running, the error output is:

```
Hit http://ftp.debian.org stretch-updates/main Translation-en        
Err http://archive.debian.org stretch/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 206.12.19.126 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 206.12.19.126 80]
Ign http://archive.debian.org stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org stretch/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 206.12.19.126 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 206.12.19.126 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Wierd thing is, it searches for Packages (which is not found) because the real file is Packages.gz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `archive.debian.org` which is the URL for archived release.  You need to use `ftp.debian.org` for actual releases.